# am getting an error after flutter version update

Tags: flutter, dart

```
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'accentColor'.
app.dart:89
      accentColor: theme.variantColor,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
theme_data.dart:290
  factory ThemeData({
          ^
: Error: The getter 'textTheme' isn't defined for the class 'AppBarTheme'.
app_bar.dart:183
- 'AppBarTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart' ('../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart').
app_bar_theme.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'textTheme'.
        style: (appBarTheme.textTheme?.headline5 ??
```

this is am getting when am running my flutter app. note:- i removed the code from my project and am running latest version of flutter and packages

i tried to run flutter clean and flutter pub get as well flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: ThemeData's accent properties have been deprecated https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties

Comment: @tomerpacific there is no code where i use ThemeData etc..

Comment: @TomaszNoinski i know but am not using that . i removed the code

Comment: @MuhammedFayis - There error you shared states that there is a file called app.dart where accentColor is defined.